# Git pushing into master failed...

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I am not sure where to search from as the error list is as long as the bottom. But generally this is what I did.

What I did:

```
git clone url .
git add abc.txt
git commit -m "testing"
git push origin master / git push
```

Error:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To ../git_abc/
```

Comment: What kind of url are you cloning? Is the origin repo a bare repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing `master` from your clone to the origin repo, where the origin repo itself has `master` checked out, and the origin repo is not a `bare` repo. `GIT` doesn't allow that.

To achieve what you are trying to do,

#### Either use a bare intermediate repo to which you push, and then pull in from this repo.

```
git clone  --bare <origin/repo> intermediate
```

On your original local repo

```
git remote add upstream <path/to/intermediate>
git push upstream master
```

On your origin repo

```
git remote add downstream <path/to/intermediate>
git pull downstream master
```

#### Or push to some other branch on the origin repo, and merge that branch into the master branch in the origin repo.

From local repo

```
git push origin master:master_to_be_merged
```

On origin repo

```
git checkout master
git merge master_to_be_merged
```

#### Or ignore these warnings and push anyway

In this case, you will have to take extra care that nothing is breaking, and this is anyway not recommended.

On origin repo, run

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

And now from your local clone, do

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: I don't understand this git clone --bare <origin/repo> intermediate where the intermediate pointing to the remote and it will copy all the .git files into intermediate directly without putting into .git folder?

Comment: ya thanks, my bad. I didn't know that the master should be in bare. But even though that's the problem why most of the tutorial out there doesn't mention it??

Comment: @EricT I guess because most of the tutorials are for beginners, and beginners don't use github or similar services instead of bare repos.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check out a branch?

Try

```
git checkout your_branch (could be master)
```

then

```
git add blah
git commit
git push origin master
```