# git - Still cannot push to non-bare repo after setting receive.denycurrentbranch=ignore

Tags: git, git-push, git-non-bare-repository

My setup is as follows:

I am running git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55) on my mac. This has a non-bare git repository sitting at `~/xyz`.

Then I am running Windows 7 64bit using VMWare Fusion on the same mac. The VM has git 1.9.5, which is the latest git version for Windows. From the VM I can clone and pull from my mac's non-bare repo `~/xyz` OK, but I cannot push to it. I have followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062732/git-pushing-into-master-failed) and set `receive.denycurrentbranch=ignore` on `~/xyz` but still gives me the same error message:

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

I have also tried setting `receive.denycurrentbranch=updateInstead` but still the same error message.

I have restarted the computer after each instance of changing any git settings.

The directory `~/xyz` is a shared directory to my VM, and I have ensured the VM has read/write access to it.

Please, anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push error '\[remote rejected\] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked)

Answer (score 5):

You need to run the command from the server where you are pushing the code not from the local repo system

```
git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the VM can use any version of Git it want, not just the old and obsolete msysgit 1.9.5 one: [git for windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/) offers [the latest 2.4.6](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/).
No setup required, just uncompress [PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want and add its bin folder to the `%PATH%`.

> I have also tried setting receive.denycurrentbranch=updateInstead

That [Git 2.3.0+ feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309) (see [the release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9874fca7122563e28d699a911404fc49d2a24f1c/Documentation/config.txt#L2155-L2160)) has to be set on the server side, not the client.

If that is not convenient, the [OP Jason L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1659097/jason-l) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552850/git-still-cannot-push-to-non-bare-repo-after-setting-receive-denycurrentbranch/31555925#comment51234470_31555925) the workaround of:

> not pushing to the mac git repo from the VM, but instead pulling the VM git repo from the mac.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to work around this problem by not pushing to the mac git repo from the VM, but instead pulling the VM git repo from the mac.

Comment: @JasonL That is indeed a possible workaround. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.